# How to disable slide open jump lists in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

In Windows 7 it is possible to open the jump lists of programs by either right clicking the item in the task bar, or by holding and sliding up with the left mouse button on the item.

However this is very annoying when switching between windows.

When I want to click on a group of windows to show the previews and afterwards clicking one of them to switch to it, it can instead open the jump list because I released the mouse button while clicking not fast enough. It happened more than once to click on "Close All Windows" instead of switching to the desired window.

I have done some research and found following names for this "feature":

- Lists Mode
- Lists View
- Slide Open Jump Lists

Found here: http://windowsforum.com/threads/how-to-disable-left-click-jump-list-help.51090/

One proposed solution was a script that fixes the mouse cursor in position while clicking. This is not a good solution for me as I had to turn of the script while gaming or doing other stuff. 
Found here: http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?t=33983002&page=3

I just want to disable this akward feature. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) can do that. It's lightweight (less that 4 MB of RAM right now on my system and no noticeable impact on CPU) and it allows many other useful tweaks.

[image: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker screenshot with appropriate option highlighted]

Comment: Just to update: in the latest version, this has been removed from the main settings dialog and replaced with an "Advanced option" called "drag_towards_desktop".  To get the same behaviour as checking that checkbox, it needs to be set to 1.